# Переменная bool c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Поясните пожалуйста как работает переменная bool в c#. 
*Хочу понять так ли я понял)*
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну мне кажется что любая документация вполне раскрывает тип этой переменной =) Это переменная которая имеет одно из значений, true или false ( так же есть неявное значение Null ). Используется она с if, do, while и for. Так же передается в результате сравнения либо других операций.

```
int a = 0;
(a == 0) ? "true" : "false" // true

(a == 2) ? "true" : "false" // false
```

В любом случае вам стоит уточнить ваш вопрос, что вам не понятно либо в чем есть сомнения.

Comment: Что значит `неявное значение null`? Тип `bool` имеет ровно 2 явных состояния, тип `bool?` имеет 2 состояния + null.

Answer (score 1):

bool переменная которая может принимать значения только true false.

bool? дополнительно Nullable

Answer (score 1):

**bool** - логическая переменная

Используется в if, while, do while, for. Она может принимать значения true или false.

К примеру:

```
public int health;

void Start()
{
// Здоровье изначально при старте
health = 100;
}

void Update()
{
if (health <= 0)
    Debug.Log("Player died");

}
```

Т.е. health при старте 100, и функция if проверяет, равняется и/или меньше ли оно нуля. Но т.к. у нас health = 100, то функция false, что означает оно выполняться не будет

Есть несколько операторов сравнения:   == (равно), != (не равно), >= (больше или равно), <=(меньше или равно).

Также можем проверить несколько значений:

```
public bool bool1;
public bool bool2;

void Start()
{
bool1 = true;
bool2 = false;
}

void Update()
{
if (bool1 == true || bool2 == true)
    Debug.Log("Complete");
}
```

Т.е. Если bool1 будет равен true ИЛИ bool2 == true, то выполняется команда

Также есть, кроме ИЛИ (||) другие - && (И), ^ (ИЛИ, но не И).